Optocoupler vs PSR
I'm learning about the design of flyback converters and noticed that optocouplers are used more often for feedback rather than primary side regulation (PSR). I understand that PSR isn't as good for voltage regulation but for single output solutions I think it would be a good option, yet it's not commonly used for this application either. PSR seems to have clear advantages such as less required components, better efficiency, and simpler implementation so I wonder why it isn't used more for single output solutions.

I'm confused – what does having a single output have to do with the quality of regulation that output should achieve? Also, you'll need to give us a source on the "better efficiency" claim – that seems surprising.

Opto's are usually used for isolation purposes.

The better efficiency calculation for PSR is usually based on the power savings from the opto and TL431 etc.  But that's probably minor compared to the space/weight savings.

My understanding is that PSR can struggle with multiple outputs since it can only compensate for one output while a feedback scheme based on opto can compensate for each output. Again I'm learning so I could be wrong.

As for isolation, PSR also offers isolation between the primary and secondary no? The auxiliary winding may not be isolated but isolation between the input and output is still achieved.

How would it be able to compensate for each output with only one primary? That's a problem that has little to do with PSR vs. opto.

Because opto feedback happens on the secondary side the error signal can be a sum of weighted inputs. I saw this somewhere in a datasheet or technical article. I'll link it if I can find it.

Poor regulation is an issue, especially at light loads.  However, it's not correct that it's not commonly used, in my experience it is. Many low power offline supplies use PSR flybacks.
I'm also not sure that PSR provides better efficiency.  In some cases, they need a clamp diode on the output that wastes power at light or no load but prevents the output from rising well above the regulation point. That destroys light-load efficiency.  So efficiency could go either way, in general I don't think one has an advantage over the other.
Also, depending on the regulation scheme, the transformer may be trickier to produce for a PSR flyback since the leakage inductance may have to be well controlled to get consistent regulation.

Thanks for answering! When I say optocouplers are used more often I should give the context that I'm interested in wall chargers between 20W to 100W and my observation is based on reviewing reference designs and teardowns of products on the market. I assumed this trend was generally applicable but it may be specific to this.

There's a push to make the no-load power consumption of wall chargers very small, since people often leave them plugged in and unconnected.  If a PSR flyback needs a no-load Zener clamp, then it will dissipate significant power without a load, which will probably not meet no-load power regulations.  So for that application PSR flybacks may need additional circuitry.  That might explain why you don't see many in your teardowns, though they do exist.

I don't know that I'd say "more often", but it would be illustrative to understand why/when/where the options are chosen.
Primary side regulation is often chosen when poor / little output regulation is required, as it saves the expense of the opto and related feedback components.  A typical flyback controller like UC3842 requires primary side aux power anyway, so the necessary low-voltage sense winding will be present; feedback can be derived directly from aux power, nothing else required.  The downside is, both aux and secondary voltages are the combination of respective leakage plus magnetizing inductance EMFs, so in general will differ.  In particular, the leakage that intercepts the primary and one winding, but not the other, manifests a spike due to primary turn-off that isn't matched between the two secondaries:

The leakage spike from the primary, couples separately into the two secondaries; if the output is loaded more heavily than aux, aux will be dominated by the leakage spike and (1) will be tall, while (2) will be squashed lower, or completely flat with the bulk of flyback (magnetizing inductance) pulse.  Or, really, in general, one or both windings will be the voltage which defines the flyback pulse, and the lighter-loaded of the two will rise up extra due to leakage.
In any case, the problem is, the output is variably loaded, while the aux is fixed.  Even if we put a fairly heavy "bleeder" resistor on the aux supply (wastes idle power),
Or if we make such a "bleeder" resistor variable, but... how do we know what load current is flowing other than putting in an opto?  You see the dilemma.
We can solve the problem in a more subtle manner:
Note that, after a few microseconds, the waveform has settled down, primary leakage having discharged, and the windings show a relatively stable voltage defined by the (magnetizing inductance) flyback EMF (and this the dominant loaded winding).  At least, this is true if the flyback flux is high enough to keep current flowing until this time -- if it stops early, we instead sample along the free ringdown, and error goes way up.
This is the method of monolithic regulators like Power Integrations LNK623, which sample the aux voltage midway along the discharge pulse (tFB, 2.55µs typ. for this part).  To ensure sufficient flux, current-mode control is not practical; instead, the on-pulse is simply timed (mind, a fixed current limit is still implemented for startup / limiting / protection purposes), and pulses are skipped when voltage is above threshold: they use hysteretic voltage regulation.  (A comparator, instead of error amp, is also cheaper in terms of chip area; and in terms of current draw, which, since the regulator is self-powered from up to 700V through the drain terminal, low current consumption is mandatory!)
Control is complicated by the fact that, inbetween pulses, we need to stay off to wait for feedback voltage to fall... but, uh, we can't tell what feedback voltage is until after a pulse...  This is a non-trivial control problem, but it seems, one they have solved ably, in any case.  The transient response is excellent, and output ripple isn't even bad (despite the hysteretic control, in particular the variable repeat rate at light load), as long as you use relatively large filter capacitance.
I've made a "precision" design with one of these, before, achieving joint regulation between two secondaries, and reasonable regulation on (primary-side) aux, of better than 5% over full load range.
Significant transformer design iteration and optimization is required to achieve this; I went through about 4 designs, settling on a two-section primary winding, interleaved with a single-layer aux winding, and multifilar (2+3 strands) secondaries.  This isn't the worst thing to wind, but all details must be communicated clearly to the winding shop -- or a reference article sent to them to reproduce.
This is a somewhat exceptional case, I think; most such adapters are in the 10% regulation range, good enough for general use, and most things won't mind (e.g. phones have a whole slew of converters anyway, to charge the battery, power the CPU, etc.).
Primary-side sensing is most practical at low power levels, and best motivated by the component cost of opto and error amp in small converters.  Hence this is a common solution for small adapters: standby power, small LED lamps, phone chargers, etc.
At higher power levels, the cost differential for the added components is less significant, while the component values required (like relatively large output capacitors) can be a bigger problem.  The issues with leakage inductance may be harder to mitigate as well, as transformer size grows (and with it, leakage inductance; or winding complexity, and attendant production cost issues, and perhaps EMI, and thus knock-on filtering or shielding costs).
As a result, optos are standard for say 20W+ power levels.  Hard-switched flyback also gives way to QR flyback, two-switch forward, and LLC resonant, methods which may not be easily (or at all) sensible by aux winding.

Optoisolators' main job is to provide high voltage isolation, but due to low capacitance coupling compared to the loop, it also has high CMRR.
Avago's optoisolators have an advantage over some cheap parts because they use a Faraday cage around the high impedance opto Rx for superior CMRR that comes from floating SMPS with unshielded inductors.
Source : https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AV02-4387EN
CM Noise is "common" (pun not intended) due to the unbalanced capacitance feedthru on each transformer line out and a flyback current loop.  There may be other noise paths depending on the SMPS design such as X Cap filters to PE gnd for floating DC outputs.
